# How to pass parameters in get request using axios?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I am trying to pass api_key in the get request parameter using axios

here is my code

```
const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3"
});
export function crudify(path) {
  function get(id) {
    return instance.get(`${path}/${id}`, {
      params: {
        api_key: "qwerasd"
      }
    });
  }

  return { get };
}
```

I expected to get the URL:

> https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?api_key=qwerasd

but instead I get:

> https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list

Comment: Can you show where you are actually building the URL using `crudify`?

Comment: API.get('/genre/movie/list')

Comment: It makes sense you aren't seeing anything there because you just pass it a path.  You could modify your `crudify` function to take a list of query parameters or something like that to append to your URL once it's been created if you wanted to explore that option.

Comment: This code works fine for me. How are you determining the URL axios is sending? Maybe you can make a working snippet using something like https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com

Comment: I'm not sure, I'm just watching Google Chrome's DevTools in the network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to append query string params directly to url:

```js
function get(id) {
    return instance.get(`${path}/${id}?api_key=qwerasd`);
}
```

Comment: and if I need to pass multiple parameters?

Comment: Just join them with `&`: `${path}/${id}?api_key=qwerasd&more=1`

Comment: You don't *need* to append the query strings. Passing parameters like this is a documented part of the Axios api.